# NSDictionary writeToURL

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

Can someone please explain what this does. I'm hoping it writes a pliant to a URL such as a web server. If not how could I accomplish such a thing?

Comment: Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BCIICEDB

Comment: The docs you link to describe what it does, but don't actually talk about local/remote URL differences, so they're not exactly the answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSURL` objects are used to describe URLs - but a 'URL' isn't necessarily an HTTP link. It can just as easily be a pointer to a local file system, or a networked file resource.

The `writeToURL` method is used to save a dictionary to a local filesystem. You can, if you want, send the PLIST representation of a dictionary to a server you run, but you'll have to both write the client networking code and (more importantly) the server-side logic to receive it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. How could I send a XML through FTP?

Comment: Through FTP? Apple actually have a nice code sample that shows how to do file transfers through FTP. You can find it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html - but do note the warning they give regarding security!

Comment: I have been trying to use WhiteRaccoon. I have everything all se up and when I attempt a file upload it just gives me Unknown Error! I wish WR was more documented. Apples example is a bit much for my comprehension at this point.